# When run rails server got a lots of errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a ruby on rails project at /home/web/Rubyonrails

When run rails server then got below errors:

```
    web@web-VirtualBox:~/Rubyonrails$ rails server
/home/web/Rubyonrails/config/application.rb:19:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /home/web/Rubyonrails/config/application.rb:18:in `tap'
    from /home/web/Rubyonrails/config/application.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/web/Rubyonrails/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/web/Rubyonrails/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /home/web/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/web/Rubyonrails/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    from /home/web/Rubyonrails/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

config/application.rb file:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Rubyonrails
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end

# Bower asset paths
Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components').to_s.tap do |bower_path|
  config.sass.load_paths << bower_path
  config.assets.paths << bower_path
end
# Precompile Bootstrap fonts
config.assets.precompile << %r(bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/[\w-]+\.(?:eot|svg|ttf|woff2?)$)
# Minimum Sass number precision required by bootstrap-sass
::Sass::Script::Value::Number.precision = [8, ::Sass::Script::Value::Number.precision].max
```

Rubyonrails/bin/rails file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

Rubyonrails/bin/spring file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# This file loads spring without using Bundler, in order to be fast.
# It gets overwritten when you run the `spring binstub` command.

unless defined?(Spring)
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'bundler'

  lockfile = Bundler::LockfileParser.new(Bundler.default_lockfile.read)
  spring = lockfile.specs.detect { |spec| spec.name == "spring" }
  if spring
    Gem.use_paths Gem.dir, Bundler.bundle_path.to_s, *Gem.path
    gem 'spring', spring.version
    require 'spring/binstub'
  end
end
```

Comment: How does your `config/application.rb` file look like - especially around line 18?

Comment: I pasted on my post above for your reference.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. You are asking two questions which seem to be unrelated. Don't do that as it results in answers that are not related. Instead, ask one specific question, or two that are very closely related.

Answer (score 1):

Change line `18` of your `config/application.rb` to:

```
Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components').to_s.tap do |bower_path|
```

`root` is not defined, but `Rails.root` is.

Answer (score 1):

In application.rb

```
# Bower asset paths
root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components').to_s.tap do |bower_path|
  config.sass.load_paths << bower_path
  config.assets.paths << bower_path
end
```

you are missing `Rails` before `root`:

```
# Bower asset paths
Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components').to_s.tap do |bower_path|
  config.sass.load_paths << bower_path
  config.assets.paths << bower_path
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added Rails before root, but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to run

```
source /home/web/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

every time you open a window then you haven't installed RVM correctly.

Carefully read "[Installing RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install)" and confirm you followed those steps.

Once you've confirmed that the installation is correct you need to set a default Ruby for RVM to use. First, list the Rubyies RVM manages:

```
rvm list
```

which returns something like:

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

then tell RVM to use one:

```
rvm use ruby-2.4.0 --default
```

Also, it's a good idea to periodically tell RVM to update itself. Run

```
rvm help get
```

at the command-line for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it solved my RVM problem. I reinstall RVM. but when I run rails server the error message still the same. I edit application.rb follow by others suggestion like this Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components').to_s.tap do |bower_path|